# What is the role of the Model.xafml file in the DevExpress XAF application

Tags: devexpress, xaf

I am working on `DEVExpress XAF` and with `Model.xafml` there all settings options are given. 
I noticed that in several classes are instructions like [`ImageName("BO_Invoice")`] or [`XpandNavigationItem("MyTest")`].

Why are there these instructions both in the class as well in Model.xafml?
Does the instruction in the class have a higher priority or the Model.xafml?
Or Are there are other meanings?

My first thought was that every change in `Model.xafml` would influence the affected class. But nothing happened after changing something like `ImageView` in `Model.xafml`.

Answer (score 4):

When an XAF application starts up, it builds the application model - the platform-independent structure containing all parameters and settings used to dynamically build the platform-specific shell (WinForms, ASP.NET, Mobile).

At first pass, XAF builds the initial model based on business classes (domain components) available in the application. In business classes, you can use [attributes](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument112701) to declare application model settings.

Then, XAF adds differences declared in the Model.xafml file to the application model. Model difference files (*.xafml) used to customise and extend the application model, add differences for specific platform only (or even for specific users), extend application by adding custom modules (plug-ins).

To learn more, read the [Application Model Basics](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument112580) article in DevExpress online documentation.